# The norm of gaussian random variables

Tags: probability, random-variables, normal-distribution

Assume $x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n$ are iid standard gaussian random variables, what is the value of
$\mathbb{E}\sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots + x_n^2}$

Comment: Hint: Your radicand is $\sim \chi^2_n$. You know LOTUS ?